# I can't find "#DD#" in text with Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find all strings "#DD#" in the text file, but my search script returns nothing, even though I know for sure that "#DD#"s are there. I have a feeling that #DD# is a bad combination of symbols, but I have no idea how to make it work. I will appreciate any suggestions.

UPD: I think I asked the question very clearly (nowhere asking to write a code for me --- I can do that myself); I just run into this weird issue, which I cannot understand. My script finds all other tags of this pattern #CC#, #KK#, #WW# and many others, except for #DD#, or any other tag that begins with #D.*. If you, mighty specialists, see no problem with this, saying so would suffice. No need to be rude.

Comment: Please post a code sample.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. We don't write code for you. Show what you have tried and we may help you to go further. No, Stackoverflow is not the please-write-code-for-me site.

Comment: My question was not about writing a code for me? Where exactly did I ask for that? I told that the problem was with these particular symbols --- and I cannot figure our why they are ignored, while "#ZZ#", "#CC#" are found without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing to do with *a bad combination of symbols*:

```
import re

str = '#DD# and #DD# more #DD#'

re.findall('#DD#',str)
['#DD#', '#DD#', '#DD#']
```

I suspect you are not reading the file correctly or it's empty, or maybe something else.. but you need to post your code.

Comment: Oooo - a palindromic rep that looks almost like your name :)

Comment: @JonClements damn now I can't upvote this ^^